# Vertices disappear after entering weight painting mode

Tags: weight-painting

I am trying to weight paint the head of this bear. In edit mode, I select all vertices of the head/ears/snout/eyes using <kbd>L</kbd> for each item. Then I <kbd>Tab</kbd> into weight paint, and the vertices "disappear."

I <kbd>Tab</kbd> back to edit mode, and get what you see here. You can see there are vertices to select on the eyes/arms/body etc, but the head and ears become only "lines" and I can no longer select them. If I "undo," then the vertices come back. Is this a bug?

[image]

EDIT: Entering sculpt mode, then edit mode, then pressing ALT-H to unhide all vertices, returns the "hidden" vertices to view, but they would "hide" again when I entered weight paint mode. I deleted the Blender application and re-installed and this has solved my problem; I am now able to select vertices in edit mode and paint on that selection in weight paint mode.

Comment: please put your file here for check

Comment: Known bug.  Workaround for now is to enter sculpt mode and alt h to unhide all vertices.  That should fix the issue, at least temporarily.

Comment: Thank you both. Nathan, your answer explained the issue and solved the problem.